# Clear username caching by windows authentication dialogue box

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.Net web application that uses windows authentication. When I access the application it prompts a windows dialog box to input the credentials and a check box "Remember my credentials" to save the user credentials. I have the following requirement for the application to ensure security,

The application should clear the "UserName" and "Password" fields on windows authentication dialog box every time he access the application, even though if he selects the  "Remember my credentials" check box during in previous login.

I tried creating a registry key "DisablePasswordCaching", but this clears only the password field but not the username. And this fix should be done in all the client machines which is not a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog box is presented by the browser in response to a 401 authentication error that IIS returns when a user attempts to anonymously access a website that has Windows Auth enabled.  The dialog is outside the control of your application (it is a feature of the browser), and whether or not you can clear the username, and how to do so, is going to be different for each browser (and possibly versions of the browser).

If it is imperative that you have control over this, then you might want to look at using Forms authentication in conjunction with the Active Directory Roles and Membership provider so you have control over the login screen.